# Google Cloud Builder randomly timesout on rails assets precompilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1, google-cloud-build, google-container-builder

I have a dockerfile that contains the following steps.

```
FROM ruby:2.4.5-slim
# more build steps
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./Gemfile ./Gemfile.lock ./package.json ./yarn.lock ./
RUN bundle install
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile --trace
# more build steps
```

Sometimes the assets will precompile perfectly within a few seconds, other times the precompilation times out. The timeout is consistent with certain builds only on Google Cloud Builder. If I restart a build that timesout, that build will timeout again.
I am able to build the image without any issues on many different machines.

I've also been able to successfully run the cloubuild steps locally without any issues.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout of the build? (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#timeout_1). You may also wish to try a large (build) machine size (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds#using_custom_virtual_machine_sizes)

Comment: @DazWilkin I have increased the timeout and tried different machines. and that has not helped either. It's a very small set of assets we use. When it does work (which is 90% of the time), it does not take any longer than fifteen seconds.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have Google Cloud Support? If so, I recommend a ticket. If not, is there a way for me to easily repro your issue? If so, I will give it a whirl and, if I can repro it, I'll chat with Engineering.